# Get size of Wordpress RSS feed?

Tags: wordpress, actionscript-3, flash, rss, filesize

### The scenario:

I have a flash website ([here](http://www.sulsc.org)) that imports some of its content from a wordpress site ([here](http://news.sulsc.org)) via the Wordpress's RSS (I added a plugin to include pages in the RSS). This isn't a brilliant idea I know, but for a long list of reasons that I won't go into it's the setup I'm stuck with :/

### The Problem:

When importing the RSS feed (it's downloaded into the SWF at runtime and read like an XML), I can't get the filesize. This means the preloader isn't accurate (I just manually guessed a number for it to work with for now, which obviously will grow over time). ***How do I get this file size?***

I know there may be certain settings on the server that compresses the feed/files (GZip or such), but I'm very unfamiliar with wordpress architecture and despite my best efforts I couldn't find where this setting would be applied.

This is the preloader update code. The 113*1024 is where I want to put rss_loader.bytesTotal (the loader of the WordPress content), but when I do rss_loader.bytesTotal returns as 0:

```
function update_loading(e:Event):void
{
    var total:Number = stage.loaderInfo.bytesTotal + (113 * 1024) + css_loader.bytesTotal;
    var loaded:Number = stage.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded + rss_loader.bytesLoaded + css_loader.bytesLoaded;
    if (total == loaded)
    {
        updatePicture(360);
        loading_mc.perc.text = "100%";
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update_loading);
        nextFrame();
    }
    else
    {
        var deg:Number = (loaded / total) * 360;
        updatePicture(deg);
        loading_mc.perc.text = String(int((loaded / total) * 100))+"%";
    }
}
```

Here's the RSS import code, though I don't believe it's very relevant:

```
var rss_xml:XML = new XML();
var post_xml:XML = new XML();
var page_xml:XML = new XML();
var rss_loader:URLLoader;
rss_loader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("http://news.sulsc.org/feed"));
function rss_loaded(e:Event):void
{
    rss_xml = XML(e.target.data);
    var rss_raw:String = String(rss_xml);
    rss_raw = rss_raw.split(":encoded").join("");
    rss_raw = rss_raw.split("\n").join("");
    rss_raw = rss_raw.split('<p style="text-align: right;">').join('<p class="right">');
    rss_raw = rss_raw.split('<p style="text-align: center;">').join('<p class="centre">');
    rss_raw = rss_raw.split('<p style="text-align: left;">').join('<p class="left">');
    rss_raw = rss_raw.split('<p style="text-align: justify;">').join('<p class="just">');
    var heading_replace:RegExp = new RegExp("(</h[0-9]>)(<h[0-9]>)","g9");
    var underline_replace:RegExp = new RegExp('<span style="text-decoration: underline;">(.*?)</span>',"gi");
    var bold_replace:RegExp = new RegExp('<strong>(.*?)</strong>',"gi");
    var italic_replace:RegExp = new RegExp('<em>(.*?)</em>',"gi");
    rss_raw = rss_raw.replace(heading_replace,'$1<p class="space"></p>$2');
    rss_raw = rss_raw.replace(underline_replace,'<u>$1</u>');
    rss_raw = rss_raw.replace(bold_replace,'<b>$1</b>');
    rss_raw = rss_raw.replace(italic_replace,'<i>$1</i>');

    var page_test:RegExp = new RegExp("http://(news.|www.|)sulsc\\.org/(|wordpress/)\\?page_id=[0-9]+","gi");
    page_xml = XML(rss_raw);
    post_xml = XML(rss_raw);
    rss_xml = null;
    for (var i:uint; i<post_xml.channel.item.length(); i++)
    {
        if (page_test.test(post_xml.channel.item[i]) == true)
        {
            post_xml.channel.item[i] = "";
            i--;
        }
        if (i == post_xml.channel.item.length()-1)
        {
            rss_loader.bytesLoaded = 113 * 1024;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing your code on a local machine or server? This [link](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?330640-ProgressEvent-PROGRESS-URLLoader-vs-Loader) will probably help you.

Comment: Thanks, but it's _not_ a problem with loading the feed. That works fine, it's just getting bytesTotal. Everything works like a charm, except bytesTotal is always 0

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with a project last year. Turns out the server wasn't returning the correct header for Flash to pick up on. I can't remember which header it needs to populate `bytesTotal`, unfortunately, but I did come up with a quick work around.

```
this.urlLoader.addEventListenever( HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS, this.statusResponse );

private function statusResponse(e:HTTPStatusEvent = null):void{
    for ( var i:Number = 0; i < e.responseHeaders.length; i++ ) {
        var current:Object = e.responseHeaders[i];
        if ( current.name.toLowerCase() == "content-length" ) {
            this.bytesTotal = current.value;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This worked for me, although it obviously relies on the server sending a `Content-Length` header.

Comment: I should have mentioned, this is in Flash IDE not flex. This sounded like a good workaround but I couldn't get it to work in my project (get a 2007 when trying to add the event listener), thanks anyway